# El significado de "nunca nadie"

Tags: definiciones, significado

La combinación "Nunca nadie" significa que *nunca hay alguien*, al menos así lo usa la gente... Pero el significado gramatical será lo contrario, ¿verdad? ¿O hay alguna regla gramatical que dice que los dos se refuerzan en este caso (como el no...nadie)? Porque se podría entender, leyéndolo literalmente, como si en *ningún momento hay nadie*.

¿La RAE escribió algo de eso? Me sorprende que tan poca información hay sobre esto.

Answer (score 4):

Yo no sé demasiado sobre reglas gramaticales, ya que no soy un ligüista ni nada parecido. Lo que puedo aportar es lo que sé sobre el uso normal del español.

Tal como yo lo entiendo, en español las dobles negaciones no significan una afirmación, por lo tanto decimos:

> **No** hay **nadie** en casa.

Si queremos indicar cuándo es que no hay nadie en casa, decimos:

> **No** hay **nadie** en casa *ahora mismo* / *por las mañanas*.

Y si queremos indicar que el hecho de que no haya nadie en casa se produce continuamente, decimos:

> **No** hay **nadie** en casa **nunca**.

Como puedes ver, en este último caso hay hasta 3 negaciones en la misma frase, pero no se anulan entre sí, sino que se refuerzan. La palabra ***nunca*** en este caso hace referencia a que el hecho es continuo en el tiempo, y como se trata de una frase negativa usamos ***nunca*** en lugar de ***siempre***.

En inglés se utiliza la palabra ***ever*** para indicar lo mismo, ya que en inglés no se puede utilizar ***never*** poque en inglés las dobles negaciones sí indican afirmación...

Otro ejemplo:

> **Nadie** ha podido abrir esa puerta. *=Nobody has been able to open that door.*
>   
>   En los últimos años **nadie** ha podido abrir esa puerta. *=In recent years nobody has been able to open that door.*
>   
>   **Nunca nadie** ha podido abrir esa puerta. *=Nobody has ever been able to open that door.*

---

EDIT: [Algo de información](http://www.rae.es/rae/gestores/gespub000018.nsf/%28voAnexos%29/arch8100821B76809110C12571B80038BA4A/%24File/CuestionesparaelFAQdeconsultas.htm#ap8) de la **R.A.E.** al respecto.

Comment: Ese texto de la RAE ya había visto, pero no da una respuesta. Sólo dice que en combinación con "no", no anula el sentido negativo. Es de ahí que surge mi dude.

Comment: No es adecuado usar el concepto de *doble negación*. Si realmente hiciéramos una doble negación, tanto en el inglés como en el español las frases se considerarían incorrectas. *nunca no hay nadie* y *there is never nobody*. ESAS cosas son dobles negaciones y están mal gramaticalmente. Pero la frase del OP no es una doble negación

Answer (score 3):

**Nunca** es un adverbio de tiempo y significa **en ningún tiempo** (jamás).
**Nadie** es un pronombre indefinido y significa **ninguna persona**.

Por tanto la conjunción de los dos viene a decir que *ninguna persona y en ningún tiempo*. Ejemplo: *nunca nadie ha ido a Marte*. Si bien se han enviado sondas espaciales, no se han enviado personas.

Puede decirse que hay una redundancia puesto que si decimos *nadie ha ido a marte* se debe sobreentender que es en tiempo alguno. Pero no que una niegue a la otra dado que se refieren a tiempo (nunca) y a persona (nadie).

Answer (score 1):

Al igual que @MikO, tampoco soy lingüista, pero te puedo decir que esa combinación de "Nunca nadie" al igual que "No (*) nadie" también sirve para reforzar lo que se dice y no anula el sentido. Es casi lo mismo que decir "Nadie jamás ..." ambas tienen connotación negativa, sin embargo solo se refuerzan.

Comment: ESTA merece POR LEJOS ser la respuesta aceptada. Tal cual decís, se comienza con negación y el segundo adverbio sólo lo refuerza. En ningún momento debemos caer en la tentación de explicarlo de acuerdo a la *doble negación* en el sentido lógico, porque ni de cerca se expresa algo como eso en este tipo de construcciones